# range query using date intervals

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a document with timestamp as `2015-05-18T19:08:35Z`. This is correctly returned in the following query.
But if I increase the time interval from 5 minutes to 10 minutes the same row does not show up in the results.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/enwiki_content/page/_search?&pretty=true" -d' {
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2015-05-18T19:04:00Z",
        "lte": "2015-05-18T19:09:00Z"
      }
    }
}  } ' > out2.txt



curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/enwiki_content/page/_search?&pretty=true" -d' {
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2015-05-18T19:01:00Z",
        "lte": "2015-05-18T19:09:00Z"
      }
    }
}  } ' > out2.txt
```

The second query above should return all the rows from first query + any other matching rows. Right?
(This is wikipedia 5 million data (more than 100 GB) if that matters.)

Comment: Can you make sure you use the correct timezone, i.e. `Z` and not `z`? Probably won't change much, but never know.

Comment: Tried. that did not make any difference. It seems both "Z" and "z" are the same.

Comment: mapping is available here... https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-mapping-dump&format=json

Comment: Interesting... Can you switch to POST instead of GET (good practice when sending payload)?

Comment: GET and POST both return the same results.

Comment: I think the reason might be because the second query returns more results and you're only getting the first 10 (by default). Try increasing the size of the query and you should get the expected record.

Comment: Thanks. It worked _search?size=100

Comment: Ok, nice. I've added an answer to make it official :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the second query probably returns more results and you're only getting the first 10 (by default).

Try increasing the size of the second query and you should get the expected record.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/enwiki_content/page/_search?&pretty=true" -d' {
  "size": 100,              <--- add this line
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2015-05-18T19:01:00z",
        "lte": "2015-05-18T19:09:00z"
      }
    }
}  } ' > out2.txt
```

or

```
                                                             add size
                                                                |
                                                                V
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/enwiki_content/page/_search?size=100&pretty=true" -d' {
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2015-05-18T19:01:00z",
        "lte": "2015-05-18T19:09:00z"
      }
    }
}  } ' > out2.txt
```

Comment: What is the max size allowed? In other words how much data can I return from elastic search?

Comment: As much as you want, but the logical limit will depend on many factors, such as your RAM (to contain the results), CPU (to process them), network (to send them). When returning results, it makes more sense to use paging with `from/size` and only request data if it is really needed/requested by the user.